# jQuery functions to toggle navbar menus

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the first JS/JQuery script I had written for my website, few months ago. It toggles/hide/show menus (and some sub-menus/interactions) when a user clicks on specific items from the navbar.

Right now I have 6 main menus, and I believe my code is far from being optimized.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).click(function(event) {
        $("#website-header #tab-lang").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-apps").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-apps #apps-reveal").delay(300).hide(0);
        $("#website-header #tab-dashboard").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-login").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-footer #tab-about").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
        $("#website-footer #tab-about #credits-reveal").delay(300).hide(0);
        $("#website-footer #tab-contact").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
    });

    // lang tab
    $("#website-header #tab-lang").hide().click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#website-header #nav-lang").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#website-header #tab-lang").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-apps").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-apps #apps-reveal").delay(300).hide(0);
        $("#website-header #tab-dashboard").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-login").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-footer #tab-about").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
        $("#website-footer #tab-about #credits-reveal").delay(300).hide(0);
        $("#website-footer #tab-contact").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
    });

    // apps tab
    $("#website-header #tab-apps").hide().click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#website-header #nav-apps").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#website-header #tab-lang").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-apps").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-apps #apps-reveal").delay(300).hide(0);
        $("#website-header #tab-dashboard").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-login").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-footer #tab-about").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
        $("#website-footer #tab-about #credits-reveal").delay(300).hide(0);
        $("#website-footer #tab-contact").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
    });
    $("#website-header #apps-toggle").click( function() {
        $("#website-header #tab-apps #apps-reveal").slideToggle(300);
    } );

    // dashboard tab
    $("#website-header #tab-dashboard").hide().click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#website-header #nav-dashboard").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#website-header #tab-lang").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-apps").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-apps #apps-reveal").delay(300).hide(0);
        $("#website-header #tab-dashboard").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-login").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-footer #tab-about").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
        $("#website-footer #tab-about #credits-reveal").delay(300).hide(0);
        $("#website-footer #tab-contact").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
    });

    // login tab
    $("#website-header #tab-login").hide().click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#website-header #nav-login").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#website-header #tab-lang").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-apps").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-apps #apps-reveal").delay(300).hide(0);
        $("#website-header #tab-dashboard").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-login").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-footer #tab-about").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
        $("#website-footer #tab-about #credits-reveal").delay(300).hide(0);
        $("#website-footer #tab-contact").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
    });

    // about tab
    $("#website-footer #tab-about").hide().click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#website-footer #nav-about").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#website-header #tab-lang").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-apps").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-apps #apps-reveal").delay(300).hide(0);
        $("#website-header #tab-dashboard").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-login").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-footer #tab-about").toggle("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
        $("#website-footer #tab-about #credits-reveal").delay(300).hide(0);
        $("#website-footer #tab-contact").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
    });
    $("#website-footer #credits-toggle").click( function() {
        $("#website-footer #tab-about #credits-reveal").slideToggle(300);
    } );

    // contact tab
    $("#website-footer #tab-contact").hide().click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#website-footer #nav-contact").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#website-header #tab-lang").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-apps").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-apps #apps-reveal").delay(300).hide(0);
        $("#website-header #tab-dashboard").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-header #tab-login").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
        $("#website-footer #tab-about").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
        $("#website-footer #tab-about #credits-reveal").delay(300).hide(0);
        $("#website-footer #tab-contact").toggle("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
        $("#website-footer #tab-contact #contact-callback").hide().css('visibility','visible');
        $("#website-footer #tab-contact #callback-message").hide().css('visibility','visible');
        $("#website-footer #tab-contact #callback-dismiss").hide().css('visibility','visible');
    });

})
```

Basically I'm repeating the same thing, when a user clicks on a navbar item, I close every other menus and open the one the user requested (and reset the sub-menus if there were any). When the user clicks on the documents (or anywhere that is outside the menu they opened) I also close everything.

I'm afraid my code, even though it works fine, might be a bit repetitive and somewhat ressources' greedy (does the `$(document).click(function(event)` trigger even when there is nothing to close?).

I'm looking for some recommendations, ideas, or models from more experienced devs than I am.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Ah I understand. I missed that rule and assumed it was okay to post the result and ask for a confirmation of the code as my post did not attract many reviewers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't query the same nodes**

One good practice is to store nodes you use repeatedly. Every time you click anywhere on the page you query the same 8 items which is expensive. Query them once and store them

```
var tabLang = $("#website-header #tab-lang");
```

then you can use the variable `tabLang` in the `events`:

```
tabLang.hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
```

**Querying IDs**

IDs are supposed to be unique. It is a little faster (and shorter) to query the ID directly than to establish its ancestry so:

```
$("#website-header #tab-lang");
```

should be:

```
$("#tab-lang");
```

**Repetition**

Seeing as most of your functions close the tabs and toggle the clicked one you could create a function that closes all tabs and call it from within the `click event`. Making sure the proper tab gets toggled instead of closed could be accomplished by checking the `tabs` state before it gets hidden and `hide` or `show` accordingly:

```
tabLang.click(function ( event ) {
    if (tabLang.is('visible')) {
        hideTabs();
    } else {
        hideTabs();
        // we want the tab to be visible so we stop the running animation
        tabLang.stop(true, true);
        // and tell it to show itself
        tabLang.show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300)
    }
});
```

You would obviously need to repeat this for every `clickable` tab.

**Further improvements**

Seeing as you already have a `click event` on the document you could move the logic for the tab clicks into that event and discriminate between the tabs by checking `event.target`. Keep in mind though that `event.target` is not a jQuery object. You could check equality like this:

```
$(event.target).is(tabLang) // returns Boolean
```

With this in mind you could also reduce the size of each `click event` if you handled the `hide / show` exception in the `hideTabs()` function, by calling it with the clicked element as an argument and do some comparisons there. (Though that won't improve performance, just file size which should not be necessary for you purposes)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer all theses suggestions !  I went ahead and applied them on my code (I've updated my post if you want to review the result). I was not entirely sure to fully understand the last paragraph so I tried a few things to handle the way tabs close if the user clicks outside of them. Anyways thank you ! It was very helpful.

Comment: I didn't see posting the result code was not allowed. No problem, and thanks !